# SQL: add a comment in the next column if there are duplicates

Tags: sql

Hoping someone can if this is at all possible.

I have the below SQL running in VBA.

What I want to do is add a column at the end of the table where for each row, if there is a duplicate in column heading "det_costheader" then I want "Yes" at the end and if there isn't a duplicate then "No".

"det_costheader" are all numbers and there are duplicates in them - I don't want to combine them as I need to know if there is a duplicate or not.

Hoping someone can help!? Or let me know if you need any other info - thank you :)

```
SELECT
     det_costheader AS 'Charter Number'
    ,c_broker AS 'Broker'
    ,cuname AS 'Customer'
    ,ch_name AS 'Route'
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ch_date_req, 103) AS 'Flight Date'
    ,SUM(c_grossmargin)/2 AS 'Gross Margin'
    ,SUM(c_grossmargin)*.05 AS 'Commissions Due'
    ,IIF(OUT.outstanding > 0, 'Yes', 'No') AS 'Outstanding'
FROM
    AT_ACS_COMMISSIONS AS COM
    LEFT JOIN
    AT_ACS_PROJECTOUTSTANDING AS OUT
      ON ( COM.det_costheader = OUT.project )
WHERE
    ch_date_req BETWEEN 'DateMin' AND 'DateMax'
GROUP BY
     det_costheader
    ,c_broker
    ,cuname
    ,ch_name
    ,ch_date_req
    ,outstanding
```

Comment: It depends on the database platform you are using. Since you referenced VBA, I'm assuming it's MS Access, which I haven't worked with in over 15 years. However, on SQL Server, you wuld be able to use a function called `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify duplicate rows.

Comment: Create a CTE that counts records grouped by det_costheader and then join this into your main query. You can just display this count or use a CASE statement to convert it into a Y/N flag (or however you want to indicate duplicates)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as well as an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can add:

```
(case when count(*) over (partition by com.det_costheader) = 1
      then 'No' else 'Yes'
 end) as is_duplicate
```